# Interactive plot of Van der Pol oscillator

Tags: differential-equations

```
Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[{x[t], v[t]}  /.
      Quiet@NDSolve[
        {x'[t] == v[t],
         v'[t] == μ (1 - x[t]^2) v[t] - x[t],
         x[0] == xv0[[1]],
         v[0] == xv0[[2]]},
        {x[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, tt}]],
    {t, 0, tt}
    ImageSize \[RightArrow] {450, 450}, 
    PlotRange \[RightArrow] 4,
    AxesLabel \[RightArrow] {TraditionalForm[x[t]], TraditionalForm[v[t]]}],
  {{tt, 10, "time t"}, .1, 20, Appearance \[RightArrow] "Labeled"},
  {{μ, 0.75, "parameter μ"}, 0, 2, 0.1, Appearance \[RightArrow] "Labeled"},
  {{xv0, {1, 1}}, {-4, -4}, {4, 4}, Locator}]
```

What is the problem of this code? It displays wrong in Mathematica.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: I can't see anything wrong (except that `TraditionalForm` wont't do anything). Maybe you can clarify what isn't working. However, at this point I would vote to close the question because after doing some editing of the copied code, it seemed to work.

Comment: The problem that I see is that `\[RightArrow]` should be `\[Rule]` or `->`.

Comment: Also, there should be a comma after `{t, 0, tt}`, the 2nd argument of `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: I further recommend `AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[x[t]], HoldForm[v[t]]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code again:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{x[t], v[t]} /. 
    Quiet@NDSolve[{x'[t] == v[t], 
       v'[t] == μ (1 - x[t]^2) v[t] - x[t], x[0] == xv0[[1]], 
       v[0] == xv0[[2]]}, {x[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, tt}]], {t, 0, tt}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}, 
  AxesLabel -> {TraditionalForm["x[t]"], 
    TraditionalForm["v[t]"]}], {{tt, 10, "time t"}, .1, 20, 
  Appearance → "Labeled"}, {{μ, 0.75, 
   "parameter [Mu]"}, 0, 2, 0.1, 
  Appearance → "Labeled"}, {{xv0, {1, 1}}, {-4, -4}, {4, 
   4}, Locator}]
```

It works for me, it's just hard to copy without messing it up.